# Set ThroughPut units via ARM template for eventhub

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-eventhub

I try to set the Throughput unit for EventHub via an arm template. I doesn't seem to find how to do this. Does anyone has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the schema:

```
"Sku": {
    "name": "Basic\Standard\Premium",
    "tier":"Basic\Standard\Premium",
    "capacity": integer # << this is capacity
}
```

schema - http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-08-01/Microsoft.EventHub.json#/resourceDefinitions/namespaces

tried deploying arm template, can confirm that's how it works.